# How to modify the algorithm of transaction selection in Ethereum private net?

Tags: mining, private-blockchain, pending-transactions

By default, miners select transactions with high fees from the mempool. So, transactions which are dependent and have a specific order can be selected randomly without respecting this order.
Will I be able to insert my own algorithm of pending transaction selection in the Ethereum private net? and how to do this insertion?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can implement your own algorithm to order the txpool. Currently, they order by gas price that make sense for mining incentive

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/6bd896a97f0c86fdb6d0538f5f839d7ea104e888/core/tx_list.go#L374

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Is there an algorithm (source code) that is already done which selects transactions by order or priority? I can't find something that helps me to begin.

Comment: you can find here, we introduce some new factor for ordering the tnx 

https://github.com/nextyio/gonex/blob/b6e070bf47d5aff7268e88b14337da2688f19d54/core/tx_list.go#L374